# How to chain 'mimetype -b' and 'find' command to get file names and file type in same csv?

Tags: linux, bash, find, mime-types

I would like to get filenames, creation dates, modification dates and file mime-types from directory structure. I've made a script which reads as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash
output="file_list.csv"

## columns
echo '"File name";"Creation date";"Modification date";"Mime type"' > $output

## content
find $1 -type f -printf '"%f";"%Tc";"%Cc";"no idea!"\n' >> $output
```

which gives me encouraging results :

```
"File name";"Creation date";"Modification date";"Mime type"
"Exercice 4 Cluster.xlsx";"ven. 27 mars 2020 10:35:46 CET";"mar. 17 mars 2020 19:14:18 CET";"no idea!"
"Exercice 5 Bayes.xlsx";"ven. 27 mars 2020 10:36:30 CET";"ven. 20 mars 2020 16:18:54 CET";"no idea!"
"Exercice 3 Régression.xlsx";"ven. 27 mars 2020 10:36:46 CET";"mer. 28 août 2019 17:21:10 CEST";"no idea!"
"Archers et Clustering.xlsx";"ven. 27 mars 2020 10:37:34 CET";"lun. 16 mars 2020 14:12:05 CET";"no idea!"
...
```

but I'm missing a capital thing : how do I get the files mime-types ? It would be great if I could chain the command 'mimetype -b' on each file found with 'find' command, and write it in the convenient column.

Thanks in advance,

Cyril

Answer (score 3):

You might try using the [`-exec`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html#EXPRESSION) option of the find command, in which the brackets `{}` represent the name of the current file.

Then, you could remove the new line when appending to an existing file: AFAIK default behavior automatically appends new content to a new line, so the `\n` should not be necessary.

Last, you want to have a closing quote after your mimetype, so you should not only use the `-b` option, but the [`--output-format`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mimetype) one, which will give you more control over what you want to display.
Hence the third command of your script should look like this:

```
find $1 -type f -printf '"%f";"%Tc";"%Cc";"' -exec mimetype --output-format %m\" {} \; >> $output
```

Comment: Thanks corbin-c it works fine ;-) the trick with ``--output-format %m\"`` is great and took off the pain I had in the neck trying to deal with a missing " at the end of each line... Thanks again

Comment: seems to work perfectly, the 50 rep bounty is for you !

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with:

```
for entry in *; do stat --printf='"%n";"%z";"%y";"' $entry; file -00 --mime-type $entry | cut -d $'\0' -f2; echo '"'; done
```

Uses a shell "for loop", to perform a `stat` on the directory entries in the current directory. Then uses `file` to get the mime type, and pipes that to `cut` to get only the mime type (by excluding the file name which is also printed by `file`).

The format for `stat` is what I believe was requested -- the file name, the last change date, the last modification date (both in ISO format, but could easily be made to UNIX seconds-since-epoch by upper-casing Z and Y).

Availability:

- `file`: probably its own package if you are on Linux? But should be preinstalled on macOS I'm guessing.
- `bash/zsh`: easily accessible both on Linux and macOS.
- `stat` and `cut`: part of [`coreutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) so should be preinstalled on most systems.